# Private docker registry and python

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm failing to use a private docker registry from python. It seems like the environment configurations are not read.

**Main steps and error**

In `/etc/docker/registries.yaml` I defined the private registry as

```
mirrors:
  "192.168.2.62:5055":
    endpoint:
      - "http://192.168.2.62:5055"
```

However, when I execute

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
image_tag = "192.168.2.62:5055/dockertest:latest"
for line in client.images.push(repository=image_tag, stream=True, decode=True):
    if 'error' in line and line['error']:
        print(line['error'])
```

I get there error message

```
Get https://192.168.2.62:5055/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

**for reproducing** the example:

(you need edit the IP to your local machine IP)

I started the private registry within a docker container using docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
   registry:
     image: registry:2
     ports:
     - 192.168.2.62:5055:5000
```

next I defined the docker file

```
%%writefile /tmp/docker_test/Dockerfile

FROM alpine:3.7
CMD ["echo","HELLO WORLD"]
```

and build it from within python using

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
image, logs = client.images.build(dockerfile = "Dockerfile",
                               path = "/tmp/docker_test",
                               tag = "192.168.2.62:5055/dockertest")

print(image)
print(logs)
for l in logs:
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `registries.yaml` is the configuration for the registry from Kubernetes. Especially `k3s`. For reconfiguring a local docker it is required to reconfigure `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add the following line

```
{ "insecure-registries":["localhost:5055","192.168.2.62:5055"] }
```